# run script after jQuery FlexBox value change

Tags: jquery, onchange, flexbox, jquery-flexbox

Here's one for a jQuery/js pro:

I haven't finished this project yet, simply because of an inconsistent behavior in part of my code…. Immediately after I wrote that, I heard one of you say, "There's no inconsistent behavior in code, only unwanted behavior."

Notes about the setup:

- Editing records in a web app
- Using .change() to initiate my scripts.
- The initial values in the fields are compared through js against
  changes made.
- The comparison checks if the new value is, 1) the same as the original, 2) an
  existing value from a list, 3) a new value not contained in the
  list.
- using jQuery FlexBox to create a google suggest-like behavior on an
  input field (possible matches are shown in a box as you type, but
  aren't forced on you).

Desired behavior:

- The user adds a new value, either by, 1) typing the complete value
  and leaving the field, 2) typing part of the value and then hitting
  tab to choose the suggested value, or 3) typing part of the value and
  then clicking the suggested value from the box.
- The logic runs after one of these events.

Problem:

- If a user clicks on a suggested value from the box (number 3 above), the logic runs
  before that value is added to the input. This is because the browser
  detected that they left the input field, thus triggering .change().
  This results in the code comparing empty strings or partially spelled
  words with the list of existing values. The logic then determines that
  their choice is always a completely new value.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Simplest one should be to just use a timeout in change handler

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've been trying, but it wasn't fixing the problem. I went back and fiddled with it again and finally realized I was setting a very timely variable outside of the setTimeout. I can spend hours trying to solve a problem like this, and it ends up being so simple!